# why the ```plot()``` function cannot change the color of graph?

Tags: r, plot, functional-programming, smoothing

I'm working on saturate B-spline basis using standard roughness penalty.

I'd like to have plots like below:
[image]

But my plot looks like this:

[image]

I don't know why my `plot()` function cannot change the color of lines. Here is my code below and could you please tell me the reason with solution? Thank you in advance!

```
library('fda')
data(CanadianWeather)
temp = CanadianWeather$dailyAv[,,1]
precip = CanadianWeather$dailyAv[,,2]
daytime = (1:365)-0.5
day5 = seq(0,365,5)
dayrng = c(0,365)
knots = day5
norder = 4
nbasis = length(knots) + norder - 2
plot(create.bspline.basis(dayrng,nbasis=12,norder))
bbasis = create.bspline.basis(dayrng,nbasis,norder, knots)
in.mat = inprod(bbasis,bbasis)
image(in.mat)
bbasis = create.bspline.basis(dayrng,nbasis=21,norder=4)
lambda = 1e6
curv.Lfd = int2Lfd(2)
curv.fdPar = fdPar(bbasis,curv.Lfd,lambda)
tempSmooth1 = smooth.basis(daytime,temp,curv.fdPar)
plot(tempSmooth1$fd)
lambda = 1e1
curv.fdPar$lambda = lambda
tempSmooth = smooth.basis(daytime,temp,curv.fdPar)
lambdas = 10^seq(-4,4,by=0.5)
mean.gcv = rep(0,length(lambdas))
for(ilam in 1:length(lambdas)){
  curv.fdPari = curv.fdPar
  curv.fdPari$lambda = lambdas[ilam]
  tempSmoothi = smooth.basis(daytime,temp,curv.fdPari)
  mean.gcv[ilam] = mean(tempSmoothi$gcv)
}
plot(lambdas,mean.gcv,type='b',log='x')
best = which.min(mean.gcv)
lambdabest = lambdas[best]
curv.fdPar$lambda = lambdabest
tempSmooth = smooth.basis(daytime,temp,curv.fdPar)
plot(tempSmooth)
tempfd = tempSmooth$fd
mtempfd = mean(tempfd)
plot(tempfd, col = 4)
lines(mtempfd,lwd = 2,col = 2)
```

Comment: Hi.  This issue is due to the FDA package "masking" the matplot command.  There is a matplot command in FDA and base R graphics.  So replace matplot() with graphics::matplot()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the reason is that the '...' (the optional arguments where you might have specified color, like you don), never reaches the plot code inside `plot.fd`

See here:

https://github.com/cran/fda/blob/master/R/plot.fd.R#L187

This is the `matplot()` call that creates the plot in your case.

### How to fix:

If you copy all the code that goes into the `plot.fd` function, and then change this:

```r
            matplot(y, fdmat, type = "l", xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim,
                xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, axes = Axes )
```

To this:

```r
            matplot(y, fdmat, type = "l", xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim,
                xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, axes = Axes, ... )
```

And save that function as something else, for example `my.plot.fd`, then it works nicely! (see below)

(just click "Raw" to get the raw text content of that github file, copy it to a text editor, modify it, paste it in R or save to a file that you source)

```
my.plot.fd(tempfd, col = 4)
```

[image]